# Как растягивать рабочее окно, а кнопки оставлять на месте?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Делаю программу (электронное пособие) и мне нужно чтобы кнопки остовались на своем месте, а рабочее окно растягивалось, в зависимости от размера экрана. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Используйте свойство формы `Align`.

Comment: Найдите книги "основы делфи". В первых главах это всё описано.

Comment: Используйте свойство кнопок и прочих элементов `Anchors`

Comment: При использовании Align кнопка растягивается во всю ширину а при Anchors она всё равно остается на месте и при изменении расширения экрана она остается там где была на экране поменьше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Допустим, у вас вот такой макет:

```
            _________________
[кнопка1]  |                 |
[кнопка2]  |                 |
           |     панель1     |
           |                 |
           |                 |
           |_________________|

           [     кнопка3     ]
           [кнопка4] [кнопка5]
```

Прописывайете вот такие якоря для элементов (`Anchors`)

```
кнопка1 = кнопка2 = [akLeft, akTop] // прилепится к верхнему левому углу
панель1 = [akLeft, akTop, akBottom, akRight] // будет растягиваться
кнопка3 = кнопка4 = кнопка5 = [akBottom, akRight] // прилепится к нижнему правому углу
```

Надеюсь принцип понятен?